# InsufficientMemoryException in Appfabric

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

> **InsufficientMemoryException in Appfabric.
>       System.InsufficientMemoryException: Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 268435456 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Ram size was-32gb. After I set `maxBufferSize="999999999"`, but still I am getting the same error. My configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataCache" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <dataCache size="Small">
    <caches>
      <cache consistency="StrongConsistency" name="default" minSecondaries="0">
        <policy>
          <eviction type="Lru" />
          <expiration defaultTTL="10" isExpirable="true" />
        </policy>
      </cache>
    </caches>
    <hosts>
      <host replicationPort="22236" arbitrationPort="22235" clusterPort="22234"
        hostId="1222497344" size="16383" leadHost="true" account="XXX"
        cacheHostName="AppFabricCachingService" name="XXX.com"
        cachePort="22233" />
    </hosts>
 <advancedProperties>
      <securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None">
        <authorization>
          <allow users="Anblicks" />
          <allow users="DefaultAppPool" />
          <allow users="Administrator" />
          <allow users="network service" />
        </authorization>
      </securityProperties>
      <transportProperties maxBufferSize="999999999" />
    </advancedProperties>
    <deploymentSettings>
      <deploymentMode value="RoutingClient" />
    </deploymentSettings>
  </dataCache>
</configuration>
```

Comment: formatted so that the configuration file would be visible.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22214660/43846